# whatsapp integration in Odoo by using python yowsup

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, yowsup

Anyone implemented WhatsApp integration with odoo, by using yowsup library, we can send message to whatsapp from terminal...If anyone successfully implemented, please help me to implement.

Comment: Did you tried anything? Where is code with error logs?

Answer (score 0):

Requires Python 2.6+, or Python 3.0+

Required Python packages: python-dateutil

Required Python packages for yowsup-cli: argparse

sudo pip install yowsup2

sudo pip install pywhatsapp

(registering your mobile number)

yowsup-cli registration --requestcode sms --phone 49XXXXXXXX --cc 49 --mcc 123 --mnc 456

yowsup-cli registration --register 123456 --phone 49XXXXXXXX --cc 49

(after registration you received password on your screen)

Python script

```
from whatsapp import Client

phone_to = '9194xxxxxxxx'
client = Client(login='9188xxxxxxxx', password='secretpasswordbase64')
client.send_message(phone_to, 'Hello world')
client.send_media(phone_to, path='/home/synconics/Downloads/test.3gp')
```

Comment: I am getting this error:: `status: fail
reason: old_version ` . How to rectify this??